# Why would you declare a variable or function that will never be used? (_foo)

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir, and after reading about underscore variables/functions [here](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/naming-conventions.html), I'm a bit confused as to their actual use case. Why bother defining a variable or function that will never be used?

I am familiar with the use of _ in pattern matching when you want to ignore some part of the match, and presumably they are closely related, but I'm struggling with this case.

Comment: Do you have an example of where the function is ignored? I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: Sorry, for functions, I mean 'not imported' rather than 'ignored'. Your answer re the variables was exactly what I needed though, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about the usecase for ignoring *functions*, but the one for ignoring variables is to give the variable a name so that if you want to unignore it in the future, you know which one to unignore. Compare these two examples:

```
def process_result({:ok, _, _, duration, count} do
  # do something with duration & count
end
```

And:

```
def process_result({:ok, _timestamp, _user, duration, count} do
  # do something with duration & count
end
```

Imagine coming back and reading this code several months later. In the first example, without looking through the code and finding where this function is called, it's not immediately clear what the two ignored values are. Was it timestamp and then user, or was it user then timestamp?

In the second example, it's *very* clear that the two values are timestamp, *then* user. If you care about either of these values later, it's *very* easy to just remove the underscore and access the variable as per normal in the function:

```
def process_result({:ok, _timestamp, user, duration count} do
  # do something with user, duration and count
end
```

---

It's worth noting also that if you use an underscore-prefixed variable, Elixir will give you a warning. Here's a little example function which will give a warning:

```
fn(_x) -> _x end
```

And here's the warning (I added in some line breaks):

```
warning: the underscored variable "_x" is used after being set. 
 A leading underscore indicates that the value of the variable 
 should be ignored. If this is intended please rename the 
 variable to remove the underscore
  iex:1
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is pattern matching used in multi-clause functions:

```
def process( :drivers_license, number ) do
  # process here ...
end

def process( :passport, number ) do
  # process here ...
end

def process( :unkown, _ ), do: nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions declared in such way will be excluded from import, but can be used internally.

Function parameters (also variables) have to be set since arity is fixed, underscore makes their use more transparent: I know my callback gets 3 params, but I only need the second one.

I don't know if there are normal variables declared this way.